# How to modify the default cmd to tcc.exe

Tags: windows, command-line

How can I change the default **cmd (%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe)** to **tcc.exe (C:\Program Files\JPSoft\TCCLE13\tcc.exe)**.

I have changed the value of **Environment Variables** -> **ComSpec**， But it still doesn't work. 
I think it should be changed somewhere in **regedit**. But I cannot find the location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does working in XP on the command line:

```
reg add "hklm\system\currentcontrolset\control\session manager\environment" /f /v comspec /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Program Files\JPSoft\TCCLE13\tcc.exe"
```

To restore the `cmd.exe` type:

```
reg add "hklm\system\currentcontrolset\control\session manager\environment" /f /v comspec /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d ^%SystemRoot^%\system32\cmd.exe
```

Edit: Restart the computer after changing the value.

Comment: Being HKLM, surely this affects all users and not just the current user account? (Unlike setting COMSPEC would, in an ideal world.) That's worth noting specifically.

Comment: I have only one user in my system. Please try it on a multiuser system and report the result here.

Comment: I don't have easy access to a WinXP system, and certainly am not going to install one just to try this...

Comment: Hi @Endoro , this method doesn't work on Win7. Do you have any other good method?

Comment: @Marslo unfortunately I don't have access to a Win7 system  :(

Comment: Hi @Endoro, that's okay, I will keep looking the other way, I will let you know if there some soluction against Win7